# Django save: When click save database not updating on admin.py

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

Here is my coding:

views.py

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("departmentt_view"))
```

relevant template:

```
<form action="{% url Condition_view department_id patient_NO %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
```

When i click save it should update the database in admin.py and return to the first page `departmentt_view`. But when i click save it return blank(whitepages) but still pointing to the same add `127.0.0.1:8000/Diablo/1/123456/Condition`

Can anyone help me on this. Thank you in advanced.

Edited program:

view.py

```
def form_valid(self, request, department_id, patient_NO):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ConditionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("departmentt_view"))
    return(reverse("form_valid"))
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^diablo/(?P<department_id>\d+)/(?P<patient_NO>\d+)/Condition/$', 'diabloreb.views.form_valid', name='form_valid'),
```

after changing to this code then i have another error saying `could not import diablorab.views.form_valid`parent module does not exist.

so i change back to this instead

```
url(r'^diablo/(?P<department_id>\d+)/(?P<patient_NO>\d+)/Condition/$', ConditionView.as_view(), name = 'Condition_view',),
```

when i change into this urls then i get the same output where its only show white pages.

relevant template

```
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
```

I am totally lost. Can anyone help me.
Thank you so much.

Comment: what is `{% url Condition_view department_id patient_NO %}`? Is it the same as your current url `127.0.0.1:8000/Diablo/1/123456/Condition`? You should try writing `<form action="." method="post">` instead if it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

```
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
```

so it submits to the same page.

If this same page is `127.0.0.1:8000/Diablo/1/123456/Condition`, then it appears that this url has 3 different parameters in it.

Your urls.py regex should point to your view function, say for example:-

```
url(r'^Diablo/(?P<department_id>\d+)/(?P<patient_NO>\d+)/condition/$',   
'yourapp.views.form_valid',
name='form_valid'),
```

And your `form_valid` view function definition should accept 4 arguments in total, like this:-

```
def form_valid(request, department_id, patient_NO):

    form = YourForm()

    if request.POST == 'POST':
        form = YourForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # do whatever you else you need.
            form.save()  
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("departmentt_view"))

    return(reverse("form_valid")
```

Notice that it's not as simple as declaring `form.save()` which is shown in your code.  You actually need to make sure that your form class (In my example code, `YourForm` is the form class I am referring) is defined and imported so that your view function can use it and do an assignment like `form = YourForm(request.POST)` so that your form class receives the POST-ed variables from the user, who is submitting the form (a "POST request", so to speak).

**EDITED**

View function accepts 2 arguments only.

Comment: Thks @Calvin for the fast reply. Let me explain more. Sorry didn't elaborate more. This page is a pop up windows which after I click save then I want it to return to the first page. In other words I would like the windows to close and return to the `departmentt_view` and also updated the database. I hope I make myself clear abit.

Comment: My urls.py `url(r'^Diablo/(?P<department_id>\d+)/(?P<patient_NO>\d+)/Condition/$', ConditionView.as_view(), name = 'Condition_view',), ` @Calvin Cheng : should i change to like this `url(r'^Diablo/(?P<Condition_view>[\w-]+)/(?P<department_id>\d+)/(?P<patient_NO>\d+)/$', 'Condition.views.form_valid', name = 'form_valid'),`.Thanks

Comment: In this case, you only have 2 arguments coming in. So my view function should be modified to be `def form_valid(request, department_id, patient_NO):`

Comment: thanks @Calvin Cheng. I Still can't save it:( I am getting the same page after i click save then its just giving me white page